# Boxeslayers to the rescue

Tags: optimization, tiling, real, packing

This is about layering boxes, not about slaying them.
We have 1,830 2×5 boxes to stack *safely*
as 10 alternating contiguous layer patterns of 183 boxes each.
Layers have identical silhouettes
that fit squarewise on a rectangular 2,000-square floor.
The pair of layer patterns is to be solved
along with the floor’s dimensions.

[image]

**Background and guidelines**

Once upon a time in packing to move we had a supply of identical boxes.
One challenge was, in a land of earthquakes and elbows,
to stack full boxes stably on the garage floor.
As width and length of a box had some irrational ratio,
we came up with an amusing pattern of alternating layers
(that turns out to be suboptimal).
This layer pair is exemplified with 2×3 boxes.

[image]

We defined ***safe** stacking* as similar to bricklaying,
where no internal abutments align between layers.

Back to 2×5 boxes of the present puzzle,
here are safe layer pairs of 4, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10 boxes.
Each pair is annotated with how efficiently
it uses rectangular floor space.
Bounty to anyone who improves on these efficiencies
or finds a safe layer pair of 5 boxes.

[image]

As an example of what to avoid as *unsafe*,
a tempting pair of 6-box layers
has internal abutments that align between layers.

[image]

*How can safely alternating contiguous 183-box layers
fit onto a 2,000 square-unit rectangular area?*

Comment: Ugh... I have only 182 boxes per layer, though I managed that in a rectangular area of 1,980 square units.

Comment: You're well on the way, @Daniel Mathias! 183 boxes and 2,000 squares is where one (surprisingly in the long run) efficient pattern overtakes another. Guessing that your approach of comment could fit 183 boxes onto a 2,002-square floor. Feel free to show and tell in any case. Don't have to render the entire solution as long as a pattern is demonstrated.

Comment: I believe all your proposed constructions are optimal, assuming that a layer has to have a single connected component.

Comment: Thank you for reassurance, @user1502040 , your contiguity assumption is correct and has been edited explicitly. I wholeheartedly look forward to kinda-answers/solutions that expand on what is posed so please post whatever you implied or have in the works.

Comment: The layer pattern I referred to is expandable with up to 96.97% efficiency. Another expandable pattern has up to 97.22% efficiency and allows for 184 boxes in an area of 2001 square units. Unfortunately, neither of these work with an *odd* number of boxes per layer. I will eventually share details, but for now here are 12- 14- and 16-box layers: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX2vU.png)

Comment: @DanielMathias I get a slightly better solution ($11 \times 15$) for $n=16$.

Comment: Not that it helps at all for this question, but I find it interesting that one can get arbitrary close to 100% efficiency for (at least some) large n.

Comment: @DanielMathias I posted my example as an answer/picture (since I don't know how to post pictures in comment)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is one way to do it, showing the pattern along with its mirror image. The rectangular area is 83 x 24 units, or 1992 square units.

> [image]

And the two combined, to show that this is a safe stacking pattern.

> [image]

I had to be carefully inefficient, as the base pattern had 180 boxes in an area of 1909 square units, and I was able to layer 186 boxes within the 1992 square unit area before hitting the magic number of 183 boxes.

Comment: F yeah!  More beautiful than the intended solution.

Comment: Gotta double check.@Daniel Mathias, which usually comes up positive. Hang in there and enjoy the well deserved +1s.

Comment: Dear @Daniel Mathias , had to take leave and might again, still reeling from solutions.  Stay tuned.  (Same to Retudin.)

Answer (score 2):

(This is not an answer to the 183 problem asked here)

High efficiency packing (arbitrary close to 100%) for far larger numbers of boxes

> [image]

Comment: I don't understand what this diagram is depicting. What does level 2 look like?

Comment: All horizontal are not shown (the inside white is filled, as well as the blue with orange layer horizontal blocks, and the orange with blue layer horizontal blocks )  , i.e. of the 20 rows, odd layers form a massive block of 5x10 in row 5..14 , while even layers have 4 10x2 massive subblocks in row 1..19  (in column 3..2, 15..24, 27..36 and 39..48)

Comment: Ah, [like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8119.jpg)

Comment: Indeed, like that

Comment: Dear @Retudin , had to take leave and might again, still reeling from solutions.  Stay tuned.  (Same to Daniel Mathias.)

Comment: @Axiomatic System, you graphically bad!  In the best sense.